# Send data from web form to web chat bot with Botframework V3

Tags: c#, botframework

I´m working with Microsoft Bot V3 and I need to send information from a web form (html form) to the chat bot and start the conversation. The Web form collect information about the name, phone, and e-mail of the user to start conversation.

How can I pass this data to the web chat and start the conversation?

I´m using C#

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [the backchannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#the-backchannel).  This way you can send things to your bot not using message activities like you would in normal bot interaction.

There is a sample of how to use the backchannel in the webchat repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/backchannel)